# How to use WebRTC and Java WebSockets to achive realtime video sharing

Tags: java, websocket, webrtc

I am trying to build an application using `JSF` and `Primefaces` to provide a One-on-One Video chat application.

I am trying to achieve similar functionality as [Primefaces Chat](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml) example. Where instead of sending `TEXT` data to each other I want to share the `mediaStream` data across pears.

So far i have tried to send the `mediaStreamURL` of one pear with another using `URL.createObjectURL(stream)`. But which seems to be that `blob:http://.....` url can not be accessed by other pears.

Could some one please point me in right direction on how to achieve this? I am well ware of hot to capture `mediaStream` from webcam, only problem I am facing is streaming the `blob` data across pears. I would be more happy if this can be achieved by using Java `websockets` or `PrimePush` or `Atmosphere` (upon which primepush is built on).

Please point me to right post if its already been discussed anywhere.

Comment: This question is not JSF/PrimeFaces related. Best suggestion: Find a framework that does this for you and can e.g. be used in an iframe or whatever.... Way to complex to build yourself imo...